# Youtube-dl -o format: can I use conditions

Tags: bash, youtube-dl

I see so many questions on `youtube-dl`'s `-f` flag. I want to know about the `-o` flag. I basically want to do:

`-o '%(artist ? artist : "Unknown Artist")s/%(album ? album : "Unknown Album")s/%(track ? track : title)s.%(ext)s'`

or if you come from some languages, this might make more sense:

`-o '%(artist ?? "Unknown Artist")s/%(album ?? "Unknown Album")s/%(track ?? title)s.%(ext)s'`

So how can I do this? The goal is to avoid `youtube-dl` from making default folders like `NA`, or to use a more appropriate field when applicable, or even pass in shell args to use as defaults when the tags don't exist.

**EDIT**
Since it was requested, here is what prompted this:

I am trying to download [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_k_chX2TlWB1Xnhm5ca6papp0bZwIC_Sd0). Let's look at these two videos in particular:

- https://youtu.be/1HTjrjjmBPU
- https://youtu.be/6nllogf68FE

When I run

```bash
youtube-dl -o '%(artist)s/%(album)s/%(track)s.%(ext)s' <url>
```

the resulting output directories are

- `The Oh Hellos/Dear Wormwood/Prelude.f137.mp4`
- `NA/NA/NA.f137.mp4`

The first one is completely acceptable, but the second one is obviously not. I would like to be able to apply a conditional formatting so that the output of the first command stays the same, and the second command outputs either

- `The Oh Hellos/Dear Wormwood/Exeunt.f137.mp4`
  or
- `Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/The Oh Hellos - Exeunt.f137.mp4`

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: The `yt-dlp` fork lets you use commas to list [alternatives](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options.

- Use `--output-na-placeholder Unknown` to make Unknown directories instead of `NA` directories.
- Create symbolic links for NA to Unknown Artist/Unknown Album:
  `mkdir "Unknown Artist"; ln -s "Unknown Artist" NA; cd "Unknown Artist"; mkdir "Unknown Album"; ln -s "Unknown Album" NA`
- Use `yt-dlp` for defaults:
  `yt-dlp -o '%(artist|Unknown Artist)s/%(album|Unknown Album)s/%(track|Unknown Track)s.%(ext)s' <url>`
  Tested: `[download] Destination: Unknown Artist/Unknown Album/Unknown Track.mp4`